# EasyDropDown.js Menu icon change to an image

Tags: jquery

I'm using http://patrickkunka.github.io/easydropdown/ to style the select form element. Can anyone tell me how i can change the Drop-Down-Icon into a image (class "carat"). I'm trying with background: url(…) but it doesn't worked.

Thanks for any help.

best regards
thomas

Answer (score 0):

Start playing with jquery code e.g. the line 84 when the span is appended, change code from

```
self.$carat = $('<span class="carat"/>').appendTo(self.$container);
```

to

```
self.$carat = $('<span class="carat"><img src="myimage.png"></span>').appendTo(self.$container);
```

then disable the background in css to show only the image

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the CSS class to use a custom image. On opening I'm flipping the background image. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RMz4y/

Here's the CSS:

```
.dropdown .carat {
    width:20px;
    height:12px;
    background: url(http://ric.general-metrics.com/wp-content/themes/ric/images/icon/caret-down-grey.png) no-repeat;
    border: 0;
}

.dropdown.open .carat {
    border:0;
    margin-top:-4px;
    /* flip background vertically */
    -webkit-transform:scaleY(-1);
    -moz-transform:scaleY(-1);
    -ms-transform:scaleY(-1);
    -o-transform:scaleY(-1);
    transform:scaleY(-1);
}
```